# Correct patten format for pattern matching?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find a sub-string matching the pattern ddddTdddd (where d is any digit and T is the letter T) in a certain string.

I'm using the PHP function preg_match() and I'm passing **'/(\d{8})(T)(\d{8})/'** as the pattern but it's not working for me. Here's how I've written the line:

```
preg_match('/(\d{8})(T)(\d{8})/', $my_string, $matches);
```

I'm assuming the why I formatted the pattern is wrong. Can anyone please confirm whether I have the correct format or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct try this

```
preg_match('/(\d{8})([a-zA-Z])(\d{8})/', $my_string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's not working for me. Also, ([a-zA-Z]) would match any character, not just the letter T, wouldn't it?

Comment: if you want only t character use 
preg_match('/(\d{8})([T])(\d{8})/', $my_string, $matches);

Comment: I'm an idiot. I needed to match 6 digits after the T, not 8. It works now. Thank you very much for your  help!